Going from Raspberry Pi to embedded / real products with SoC?
Imagine having built something like Amazon's Alexa yourself. You've used all that nice HTTP / network libraries for Python and other developer-friendly things. Maybe you are also using a Python library for NFC. Now you want to turn this in a real product, maybe with a SoC that is smaller and cheaper than a Raspberry Pi.
How would that look like from a developer perspective? There are SoCs with an ARM processor, but that alone won't give you a Linux like Raspbian that can run e.g. Python, right? Does one need to switch to C programming for a real product? Or build my own Linux that works on a SoC with ARM processor?

Got a feeling you are new to this. Python is an interpreted language. So you need a lot of already loaded up and running software to interpret the Python software. That takes space most $5 and less microprocessors can not spare. That is why people use compiled languages like C. I think you already know this. But just in case, a compiled language turns code into executable files specifically for the target processor. In some cases, all you need is to "burn" the executable file into the embedded processor and you are off and running. If that's not bad enough, python runs ~100s of times slower.

@st2000 what nonsense! While a well constructed python program may be slower than a well constructed c program (many of mine less than 50% slower) a good python program can be orders of magnitude faster than most equivalents but more than compensated by ease of coding. You need to use the appropriate tool for the task.

Stop. I concede it may not be 100 times. However I've heard some say as much as 1000. I think the best answer to this debate can be found here in this stackexchange Q/A. Which echos your sentiment of using the appropriate tool for the task. Back to the question here. You can use a form of Python on an embedded processor. But you might find it more expensive in the long run.

@me.at.coding, you have a rep of over 17k on stackoverflow.com. You probably already know what overhead an interpreted language like Python needs. So, is this really an embedded question (doesn't really deal w/RPis)? If so, the quick answer is that companies go embedded to save (production) money. Software isn't free, but a lot of companies act so. So, maybe, the real question ... can Python survive a constant push to get the BOM cost down. Maybe you can get Python to run on a $30 processor. But what about a $10 processor?

Have a look at MicroPython, a special version of Python optimised for microcontrollers.
It can run on boards, like the Raspberry Pi Pico, which costs less than $5 (but probably not a good choice for an Alexa-like application).
